# afnetworking - exc_bad_access in startMonitoringNetworkReachability

Tags: objective-c, ios, exc-bad-access, afnetworking

For a project I have to use AFNetworking. Got fresh copy from github and the iOS example project seems to be working.

However - when I copy over the "AFNetworking" folder to a new Xcode project and try to make a http call, it crashes in the AFHTTPClient's initializer

So in [AFHTTPClient initWithBaseURL:] there's this code:

```
#ifdef _SYSTEMCONFIGURATION_H
    [self startMonitoringNetworkReachability];
#endif
```

and it looks really stupid but

1) WHEN I don't link SystemConfiguration - the project doesn't compile

> (Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
>   -[AFHTTPClient startMonitoringNetworkReachability] in AFHTTPClient.o)

2) WHEN I do link SystemConfiguration - the project crashes at runtime inside startMonitoringNetworkReachability with EXC_BAD_ACCESS:

```
SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(self.networkReachability, AFReachabilityCallback, &context);
```

Did anybody have this problem? From the way they praise their lib on github I thought it'd be more polished.

Comment: still not working for me, anyone ?

Comment: do you have any solutions? I have an app that has 2 targets, it works in one target but doesn't work in another target. It's so weird.

Comment: it's really weird indeed, still no solution for that

Comment: Is your baseURL nil? It will crash if it is nil.

Answer (score 6):

It will crash if your baseURL is nil.

Comment: This fixed it for me. I was unit testing the condition when an invalid or nil baseURL was used.

Comment: FYI, a `nil` `baseURL` will now throw an exception in the latest AFNetworking.

Comment: @mattt...still crashing for me. What version throws an exception?

Comment: Also, it seems to crash if your `baseURL` is an `NSURL` with an empty string. This is quite annoying when dealing with requests for unknown URL structures - e.g. fetching an image from a URL specified in the response of a HTTP request.

Answer (score 5):

As per [the documentation](http://afnetworking.org/Documentation/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock%3a):

> This method requires the SystemConfiguration framework. Add it in the active target’s “Link Binary With Library” build phase, and add #import  to the header prefix of the project (Prefix.pch).

You included the framework, but did you add `#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>` somewhere in the project?

Comment: the import to SystemConfiguration is in my .pch, but it still crashes the same way ...

Comment: yeah looks like the only way for me was to comment [self startMonitoringNetworkReachability]

Comment: Same problem here. Could solve it the same way by commenting [self startMonitoringNetworkReachability]

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the Xcode 4.5.2. I've added the framework and added to the pch but the compiler is still complaining. UPDATE oh lovely xcode somehow lost my linking settings completely. It's fine now...

Comment: @shawnwall how did you restore your linking settings?